# How do I pass a Type to a statelles component in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Well, I would like to use one component to render differents types of data, since im using typescript, i need to pass the type of data my flatlist will be using, by now, i only have music and playlist. Is there a way to pass these types by father? Because i would like to reuse these component

User type

```
type userType = {
    id: string
    name: string
    email: string
    password: string
}
```

Playlist type

```
type playlistType = {
    id: string
    name: string
    user: userType
}
```

Music type

```
type musicType = {
    id: string
    name: string
    artist: string
    album: string
    releaseyear: Date
    genre: string
    duration: string
    user: userType
}
```

The Component

```
const scrollableView: React.FC<scrollableViewProps> = (props /* There is nothing coming to props yet */) => {
    return (
        <FlatList <Type of data that cames>
            /* The settings for flatlist */
        />
    )
}
```

The Father component that will call the list twice

```
const Dashboard: React.FC<DashboardScreenProps> = ({navigation}) => {
    let {loggedUser} = useContext(UserContext)
    let [fetchedData, setFetchedData] = useState<fetchedDataType>({
        playlists: [],
        musics: []
    })

    /* Some code here thats not important */

    return (
        <View style={Style.container}>
            <View>
                <Text>Playlists</Text>
                <ScrollableView /> //The component I would like to pass playlist type
            </View>

            <View>
                <Text>Musics</Text>
                <ScrollableView /> //The same component I would like to pass music type
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union type. The `|` operator is basically an `OR` for types.

```
type scrollableViewProps = {
  data: musicType | playlistType
}
```

Comment: Idk why i didnt thought about that... Sometimes solution is very simple. Thanks! Make this by now